# É possível definir uma tag HTML em uma string C#?

Tags: c#, html, string

Tenho a seguinte string escrita em C#:

```
string Descricao = "Você ficou muito tempo inativo, e por isso sua sessão caiu. Retorne para a página inicial para continuar."
```

Gostaria de colocar o trecho `sessão caiu` da string dentro de uma tag HTML, mais ou menos assim:

```
Descricao = "Você ficou muito tempo inativo, e por isso sua <span style="font-weight: bold">sessão caiu</span>. Retorne para a página inicial para continuar."
```

É possível? Estou tentando conforme o código acima, porém estou obtendo isso: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Com certeza é. Você mesmo fez isso no exemplo da pergunta.

Comment: @LINQ não está funcionando quando eu mostro a string. Fica como mostrado na imagem.

Comment: @RicardoAlves Esse é o tipo de coisa que deveria estar na pergunta, não é fácil deduzir isso. Enfim, outra coisa importante que não tem na sua pergunta: **qual o código que você usa para mostrar essa string**?

Comment: @LINQ, esta string é uma propriedade de uma classe chamada  `MensagemErro`. Um  objeto de `MensagemErro` é passado para a view utilizando ViewBag, e então eu o mostro assim: `@mensagemErro.Descricao`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa usar o helper [`Html.Raw()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/gg480740(v=vs.118).aspx)

```
@Html.Raw(mensagemErro.Descricao)
```

[Veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tE85FU)